# my Django form is showing an error when i tried creating an user object

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

In my Sign up form I tried to create an object called myuser from Django.contrib.auth.models
[this is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKLAI.png) 
It's showing an error

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        
     fname = request.POST['fname']
     lname = request.POST['lname']
     email = request.POST['email']
     pass1 = request.POST['pass1']
     pass2 = request.POST['pass2']

    myuser = User.objects.create_user( fname , email , pass1)
    myuser.first_name = fname
    myuser.last_name = lname
    
    context = {}
    return render(request, '/Users/tanajkhanuja/Desktop/bee/main/templates/main/Signup.html', context)
```

Comment: Error says it all, you are referencing fname before assignment

Comment: i don't get it what should i do, very new to Django

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Error you are experiencing means that you are trying to create user with variable you did not yet assigned. That's because you are assigning fname, lname, email, pass1 and pass2 only if it's POST request, but to input these values in form first is made GET request. You should move creating `myuser` inside that if statement.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        
        fname = request.POST['fname']
        lname = request.POST['lname']
        email = request.POST['email']
        pass1 = request.POST['pass1']
        pass2 = request.POST['pass2']

        myuser = User.objects.create_user( fname , email , pass1)
        myuser.first_name = fname
        myuser.last_name = lname
        myuser.save()
    
    context = {}
    return render(request, '/Users/tanajkhanuja/Desktop/bee/main/templates/main/Signup.html', context)
```

After you change User fields values you should also call .save() on it to save made changes